# Threading Conway's Game of Life gives "variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final"

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying to update a bit of my Java since I work a lot with legacy code and we don't even have Java 8 there (meaning lambda expressions are not a part of it). So I got a project to do some threading and now I'm exhausted and can't understand anymore my errors quite well. At the moment, I have some `<identifier> expected` errors, but I'm pretty sure they are happening because my `{}` are misplaced somewhere. So I'm here to humbly ask some help to figure out what the heck I'm doing wrong right now. Please and thank you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Life implements Runnable {

    static double second = 0.001;
    static long initial = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final int l; // Final is required for lambda expressions

    public void run() {
        // Needed to comply with the Runnable interface
    }

    // A simple Java program to implement Game of Life
    // From: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-conways-game-of-life/
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int M = 10, N = 10;

        // Intiliazing the grid.
        int[][] grid = {
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 },
            { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 }
        };

        // Displaying the grid
        System.out.println("Original Generation");
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                if (grid[i][j] == 0)
                    System.out.print(".");
                else
                    System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
        nextGeneration(grid, M, N);
    }

    // Function to print next generation
    static void nextGeneration(int grid[][], int M, int N) {
        ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        int[][] future = new int[M][N];

        // Loop through every cell
        for (int l = 1; l < M - 1; l++) {
            Thread t = new Thread (() -> {
                for (int m = 1; m < N - 1; m++) {

                // finding no Of Neighbours that are alive
                int aliveNeighbours = 0;
                for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
                    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                        aliveNeighbours += grid[l + i][m + j];
                        System.out.println( "Alive Neighbours Runtime: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - initial) / second + " seconds.");
                // The cell needs to be subtracted from
                // its neighbours as it was counted before
                aliveNeighbours -= grid[l][m];

                // Implementing the Rules of Life

                    // Cell is lonely and dies
                    if ((grid[l][m] == 1) && (aliveNeighbours < 2))
                        future[l][m] = 0;

                    // Cell dies due to over population
                    else if ((grid[l][m] == 1) && (aliveNeighbours > 3))
                        future[l][m] = 0;

                    // A new cell is born
                    else if ((grid[l][m] == 0) && (aliveNeighbours == 3))
                        future[l][m] = 1;

                    // Remains the same
                    else
                        future[l][m] = grid[l][m];
                    }
                });

                t.start();
                threads.add(t);
            }

            for(Thread t : threads)
                t.join();
        }

        System.out.println("Next Generation");

        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                if (future[i][j] == 0)
                    System.out.print(".");
                else
                    System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    System.out.println( "Total runtime was: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - initial) / second + " seconds.");

}
```

Comment: The answer to this question (given by Tom H., below) shows that it's not really a question about threads. I'm removing the multithreading tag, and substituting the lambda tag instead.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up, @SolomonSlow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation is certainly all over the place. Many editors will fix that for you.

A couple of your `for` statements don't have associated braces, which look as if should be present. I strongly suggest always using braces with `for`, `if`, `while`, etc.

The `Runnable` lambda supplied to the `Thread` constructor is using `l` from the outer scope. Presumably you want the value of `l` at the time the `Thread` was constructed, rather the last value set at execution time. The easiest fix is just to copy to a local value immediately within the `for` loop.

Comment: That might be it (the local variable constructed). Thanks a bunch!